# Order Table by its Foreign Key's Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a comments table with a `post_id` foreign key for posts table. The comments table has `likes/dislikes` columns. How do I order the `posts` by the number of `likes` or `dislikes` in the `comments table DESC`?

The comments and posts are loaded separately. The comments API works well and orders the comments accordingly (most liked/disliked), however when displaying the posts, I order them by `posts.comments DESC` as I don't have a workaround to this

```html
<?

switch ($orderReactions) {
  case "pdt":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id ORDER BY posts.posted_at";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND tags=:tag ORDER BY posts.posted_at";
    }
    
    break;
  case "mlp":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND posts.likes != 0 ORDER BY posts.likes";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND tags=:tag AND posts.likes != 0 ORDER BY posts.likes";
    }
    
    break;
  case "mdp":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND posts.dislikes != 0 ORDER BY posts.dislikes";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND tags=:tag AND posts.dislikes != 0 ORDER BY posts.dislikes";
    }
    
    break;
  case "mcp":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND posts.comments != 0 ORDER BY posts.comments";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND tags=:tag AND posts.comments != 0 ORDER BY posts.comments";
    }
    
    break;
  case "mlc":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND posts.comments != 0 AND comments.likes != 0 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY comments.likes";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND tags=:tag AND posts.comments != 0 AND comments.likes != 0 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY comments.likes";
    }
    
    break;
  case "mdc":
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND posts.comments != 0 AND comments.dislikes != 0 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY comments.dislikes";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND tags=:tag AND posts.comments != 0 AND comments.dislikes != 0 GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY comments.dislikes";
    }
    
    break;
  default:
    if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id ORDER BY posts.posted_at";
    }else {
      $orderBy = "WHERE users.id = posts.user_id AND tags=:tag ORDER BY posts.posted_at";
    }
    break;
}

//posts from users followed by current logged in user + logged in user
if ($orderTags == "alltags") {

  $followingposts = $db->query('SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, posts.dislikes, posts.tags, posts.user_id, users.`username`, users.`profileimg` FROM users, posts
    '.$orderBy.' DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '.$start.';');
  
}else {

  $followingposts = $db->query('SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, posts.dislikes, posts.tags, posts.user_id, users.`username`, users.`profileimg` FROM users, posts
    '.$orderBy.' DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '.$start.';', array(':tag'=>$orderTags));

}

?>
```

**UPDATE**

The code is updated to reflect the `INNER JOIN` I added that fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that you are writing a site something like Stack Overflow where you have multiple comments (answers) and each can have likes and dislikes (up and down votes).

I think that the best thing that you can do is to take all of this and assemble it into a stored procedure. From there you can pass in a parameter that will determine the ordering. As far as the actual issue you are having you could do an inner join on the posts table from the comments table and then you would be able to say simply order by comments.likes and comments.dislikes.

The following is in proper syntax for mssql server, but I am sure can easily be converted to mysql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetPostsByNumberOfComments @OrderByType VARCHAR(50)
AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM Posts
          INNER JOIN Comments ON Comments.PostId = Posts.PostId
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @OrderByType = 'CommentLikes' THEN Comments.Likes
        WHEN @OrderByType = 'CommentDislikes' THEN Comments.dislikes 
        WHEN @OrderByType= 'PostLikes' THEN Posts.likes
        WHEN @OrderByType= 'PostDislikes' THEN Posts.dislikes
        ELSE Posts.PostId
        END DESC
 END;
```

Comment: yeah that's what I'm trying to do but I don't know SQL that well, could you give me an example statement?

Comment: @MaxNjoroge I have edited the answer with an example of something that you may use, note that this is in the syntax for mssql server, but I would think that it would be a trivial conversion ot mysql. Hope this helps.

Comment: updated my code thanks to your answer that got me thinking

Comment: @MaxNjoroge happy to help. If this answer has fixed your issue, please mark this as the accepted answer (large green check mark). Thank you.